# EEG blink detection algorithm for neurosky mindwave?

Tags: c++, python, c, arduino

This might be a long shot but does anyone know how I can implement a blink detection algorithm using the eeg raw data? I've tried just detecting a spike in brain activity but it also gives a false positive whenever the electrode moves on my forehead.

Comment: I know where I'd like to apply the electrode....

Comment: Hospital name please? Fear!!! :P

Comment: You'd probably need a computer vision learning algorithm and blink at it again and again and again and .....

Answer (score 2):

eye blinks in EEG data aren't actual waves they are actually artifacts due to the potential difference between the cornea and the retina. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography#Biological_artifacts) they are usually in the 4-7Hz or 8-13Hz.

They are detectable in the fp1 and fp2 , which are  closest to the eyes.

[Here is a useful paper about removing the artifact in question](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/~jung/artifact.html)
 you might also want to look into [Independent Component Analysis (ICA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis) and [Regression Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_Analysis_of_Time_Series) This is something thats going to take a lot of research from you.